# Mock non-virtual method C++ (gmock)

Tags: c++, mocking, googlemock

I have class

```
class CSumWnd : public CBaseWnd
{

 private:
 bool MethodA()
}
```

Please can you help how to mock `MethodA()` without making virtual,
I didn't understand the concept of [hi-perf dependency injection](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#mocking-non-virtual-methods-mockingnonvirtualmethods)

Comment: Your link is dead - could you update it? I'm not able to find the exact same page, maybe [this one](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/googletest/+/refs/tags/release-1.8.0/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#mocking-nonvirtual-methods) is sufficient?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It means you will have to templatize your production code. Using your example:

`CSumWind` class definition:

```
class CSumWnd : public CBaseWnd
{

 private:
 bool MethodA()
};
```

Mocked `CSumWnd` class definition:

```
class MockCSumWnd : public CBaseWnd
{

 private:
 MOCK_METHOD(MethodA, bool());
};
```

Production class which have to be tested with mocked class `CSumWind`. Now it becomes templated to provide using `CSumWind` class in production code and `MockCSumWnd` class in tests.

```
template <class CSumWndClass>
class TestedClass {
//...
   void useSumWnd(const CSumWndClass &a);

private:
  CSumWndClass sumWnd;
};
```

Instantiation of `TestedClass` in production:

```
TestedClass <CSumWnd> obj;
```

Instantiation of `TestedClass` object in test executable:

```
TestedClass <MockCSumWnd> testObj;
```

Comment: To keep your 'production' code clean, I find it helpful to do this:
template <class CSumWndClass> class TestedClassTemplate { ... }, and then do typedef TestedClassTemplate<CSumWndClass> TestedClass;

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1127918/49972 for information on the consequences of doing what you propose.

Comment: I am facing issue in `MOCK_METHOD(MethodA, bool());` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46542373/how-to-mock-non-virtual-methods-using-googlemock?noredirect=1#comment80038793_46542373 I am getting error specified in the question above

Comment: MOCK_METHOD should be replaced by MOCK_METHOD0 // 0 parameters. There is should be ";" after "bool MethodA()" as well. Unfortunately, the idea is still not clear for me...

Comment: Mind writing the body of your method, to make it clear what it should do ?
void useSumWnd(const CSumWndClass &a);

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to change the existing code, here is a specific solution for VC++ I'm working on (https://github.com/mazong1123/injectorpp). The brief steps are:

1. Leverage DbgHelp.h to retrieve all methods' symbols and memory addresses of a class. Basically it retrieves meta info from .pdb file at runtime.
2. Compare the user input to-mock method symbol with step 1's output, get the to-mock method's memory address.
3. Leverage windows api WriteProcessMemory to change the entry bytes of the to-mock method, that is something similar as: __asm {move eax, 1; ret}.

Let's put key code here.

1. Retrieve methods' symbols and addresses of a class. Below is the key idea of the implementation. The full source code is availiable at https://github.com/mazong1123/injectorpp/blob/master/injectorpp/ClassResolver.cpp

   ```
   // Retrieve class symbol.
   if (SymGetTypeFromName(this->m_hProcess, modBase, className.c_str(), classSymbol) == FALSE)
   {
       throw;
   }

   // Get children of class - which are methods.
   DWORD numChildren = 0;
   if (SymGetTypeInfo(this->m_hProcess, classSymbol->ModBase, classSymbol->TypeIndex, TI_GET_CHILDRENCOUNT, &numChildren) == FALSE)
   {
       throw;
   }

   // Get methods info.
   if (SymGetTypeInfo(this->m_hProcess, classSymbol->ModBase, classSymbol->TypeIndex, TI_FINDCHILDREN, methods) == FALSE)
   {
       throw;
   }

   // Retrieve all methods.
   for (DWORD i = 0; i < numChildren; ++i)
   {
       ULONG curChild = methods->ChildId[i];

       // Resolve function.
       Function resolvedFunction;
       this->m_functionResolver->Resolve(classSymbol->ModBase, curChild, resolvedFunction);

       // Add the resolved function to the output.
       resolvedMethods.push_back(resolvedFunction);
   }
   ```
2. Step 2 is trival. It's only text comparing and processing.
3. How to inject the magic asm to change the method behavior: (The full source code is available at https://github.com/mazong1123/injectorpp/blob/master/injectorpp/BehaviorChanger.cpp)

   ```
   // A magic function to change the function behavior at runtime
   //
   // funcAddress - The address of the function to be changed from.
   // expectedReturnValue - The return value should be changed to.
   void BehaviorChanger::ChangeFunctionReturnValue(ULONG64 funcAddress, int expectedReturnValue)
   {


   // The purpose of this method is to change the return value
   // to what ever int value we expected.

   // Therefore, we just need to inject below asm to the header of specific function:
   //
   // mov eax, expectedValue
   // ret
   //
   // Above asm code tells the function to return expectedValue immediately.

   // Now let's prepare the asm command.
   byte asmCommand[6];

   // mov
   asmCommand[0] = 0xB8;

   // The value.
   asmCommand[1] = expectedReturnValue & 0xFF;
   asmCommand[2] = (expectedReturnValue >> 8) & 0xFF;
   asmCommand[3] = (expectedReturnValue >> 16) & 0xFF;
   asmCommand[4] = (expectedReturnValue >> 24) & 0xFF;

   // ret
   asmCommand[5] = 0xC3;

   WriteProcessMemory((HANDLE)-1, (void*)funcAddress, asmCommand, 6, 0);
   }
   ```

Comment: Looks interesting. I would love to see something similar for GCC/Clang.

Comment: @hedayat I'm planning to do this. Recently I've almost finished the x86 Windows part. Stay tune.

Answer (score 2):

Try [CppFreeMock](https://github.com/gzc9047/CppFreeMock) and some others mentioned [here](https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?cid=4c6fdc828365b80e&id=documents&resid=4C6FDC828365B80E%2128191&app=OneNote&authkey=!AtpjZailG7DIcVg&&wd=target%28%2F%2FDesign%20notes.one%7Ce625ee03-bb70-3e4d-b6a2-6eea23277768%2FCan%28if%20can%2C%20how%5C%29%20we%20mock%20non-%7Cdd2d9216-c645-bc4d-a0a5-549489f62b0e%2F%29).

Example:

```
string func() {
    return "Non mocked.";
}

TEST(HelloWorld, First) {
    EXPECT_CALL(*MOCKER(func), MOCK_FUNCTION()).Times(Exactly(1))
        .WillOnce(Return("Hello world."));
    EXPECT_EQ("Hello world.", func());
}
```

Comment: That second link for me points to a OneDrive login. Also rather than using just "here" as a description it would be better to put something more descriptive so the document can still be found if the link dies in the future.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to add more than 2 links in one answer, update the link of "here", no need login any more. The full doc can be find in github.

Comment: looks like it fails to compile with the current gmock

Comment: @Louix It seems to me that you are the author of CppFreeMock. You should disclose that in the answer.