# When mocking a class via MOCK_METHOD, does it need the override keyword?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

Lets say I have

```cpp
class Foo {
 public:
    VIRTUAL_FOR_TEST void bar(int i);
};
```

where it's mocked via

```cpp
class FooMock : public Foo {
 public:
    MOCK_METHOD(void, bar, (int), ());
};
```

Foo should only be virtual for the sake of unit testing as there's no needed inheritence for it in production code. Do you still need to provide the `override` keyword to `MOCK_METHOD`?

Edit:

If `override` is needed, why is it optional to enter? Why isn't `override` default to `MOCK_METHOD`?

Comment: *"Foo should only be virtual for the sake of unit testing"* - So you are testing a different version of the code than the one you are actually deploying? That's incredibly ill-advised - possibly even unethical - just ask [Volkswagen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volkswagen_emissions_scandal).

Comment: Foo isn't being inherited by anything besides a mock class for mocking purposes. Why would it need to be virtual in production?
I don't follow the Volkswagen reference.

Comment: You are right, it's indeed a code smell. However, the correct reaction to a code smell is to fix the design of the components in question, not cheat just so we can say we "tested the right way".

Comment: Might be a dup: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5777733/4641116

Comment: @davidj361 The Volkswagen reference is that they had special code that run emission control when under test of environment protection. Normally that feature was disabled, so while it passed tests to be approved for selling, it was actually violating the norms several times.

Comment: If you don't want virtual calls at runtime, use static polymorphism and let template code select what class to instantiate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`override` is never required. It was added in C++11 to help programmers convey intention clearly and to catch silly typos by making compiler throw an error if method marked with `override` does not in fact override anything.

`MOCK_METHOD` is a macro that expands to a regular function declaration (well, this and another function that is the mock body). Since you aren't required to add `override` specifier in any case, you aren't required to do so here either. And I had used `MOCK_METHOD` without `override` as a workaround for GMock limitation (it couldn't mock a function that returns a move only type back in the day).

It is definitely a good idea to add `override` since it helps to catch a change in code without having to wonder "why does this mock not get called". While I somewhat agree with commenters that you should test code that you execute, I also think one should not modify code just for testing purposes. Advice to "change your design" works in Java where you have to pay the cost of `virtual` functions anyway, but not necessarily in C++.

Comment: Why isn't override just defaulted in if it's used 95% of the time?

Comment: @davidj361 Default where? Making it default in the language would be a breaking change and hard to execute (would you rather have `nooverride` specifier? Where should it be used? If function has same name as virtual function in base class, should it throw error, even if it would normally be shadowing and not overriding?). Making it default in GMock only would be weird and inconsistent (no other function specifier is applied automatically, and it wouldn't be easy to create a `nooverride` specifier for that).

Comment: _It is definitely a good idea to add override since it helps to catch a change in code without having to wonder "why does this mock not get called"_

I didn't understand this part. What do you mean by the mock not getting called? Can you give an example?

Comment: Say, you have a `class Foo` with method `virtual void bar();`. You mock it, it works fine. But then one day you refactor your code and change the method to `virtual void bar(int);`, or maybe rename it to `virtual void baz();`. With `override` on mock, compiler will stop you right there and force to update the mock. Without `override`, it will happily compile everything and if you run the tests, they will fail, because mock wasn't updated. This example is not very convincing, but things like that do happen in complex code, and they can be hard to track down.